# android eclipse dynamically set list adapters child TextView width

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, width, listadapter

I have a list that is populated by a listadapter that specifies a layout like so:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter trips = 
new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.it_menu_home_row, tripsCursor, from, to);
```

Inside of that layout is a textview.  I would like to be able to dynamically change the width of that textview through code.  I have tried just referencing the textview ID with findViewById, but when I try to manipulate it, I get a null pointer exception.

Is there a simple way reference the textview of a listadapters layout?

I am trying to reference the text view like I would if it was sitting in the base layout of the activity:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTV);
```

I don't know if I have to somehow iterate through each of the list items and manually set the textView that way (and if I do I am not sure how), or if I just have to reference it once, etc

Comment: I think you need to put some more code. How are your referencing the TextView in each item in the list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use SimpleCursorAdapter you provide the textFields via the constructor itself. In the snippet you have given, `to` should be an array of id's of the TextView's present.
For example if your layout file has a TextView with the id: `"@+id/my_textfield"` then you should pass in your constructor an array: `int to[]=new int[]{R.id.my_textfield};`

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't think of that.  I am already referencing that TV to change the text itself...  Dumb thought process on my part, but great point on yours! Thanks!